While using spring gateway, oauth server, and resource server can only log out when log out of the gateway and then log out of the oauth server
Hi I'm new to the spring library and have set up a authorization server, resource server, and gateway all as seperate projects. Everything communicates just fine but I've noticed that to log out of the resource server I need to log out of both the gateway by calling 127.0.0.1:{myGatewayPort}/logout and then manually going to localhost:{myAuthorizationServerPort}/logout.
Now I'm not sure but I believe the reason for this is that the jwt token is being stored on both the gateway and authorization server so if I don't log out of both then the token is not deleted properly.
Can someone explain to me what is going on here. My setup is very basic and from the spring documentation for the most part. Any help is appreciated.
